# Calculate the sum of all the six-digit numbers you can build using $1,2,3,4,5,6$

Tags: combinatorics

Consider all the six-digit numbers you can form using the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6 $(Each digit is included exactly once in each number). Calculate the sum of these numbers.

b) Calculate the sum of these numbers where each digit can be included several times in each number.

I haven't found a good way to calculate this. Especially b, I know there are $720$ numbers and $120$ of them have $1$ in unit digit, and I think $120$ has $6$ in unit digit? (I'm not sure if it's correct tho)

Comment: What about looking at the number of numbers with a particular digit at a particular place - then the contribution of that digit at that place would be say $1 \times 10^p \times N$ if there are $N$ numbers for $1$ at place $p$

Comment: Your strategy is only true for part a). For part b), there are $6^6$ possible numbers (think about why).

Answer (score 3):

For problem a), each digit is going to appear exactly 120 times as the first digit, second digit and so on. So the answer is

$120*111111*(1+2+3+4+5+6)$.

For problem b), it is the same but instead of $120 = 5!$, we take $7776 = 6^5$.

Comment: I don't quite follow why you multiply  (1+2+3+4+5+6) with 120*111111?

Comment: Lets look at the digit 3. It is going to be the second digit 120 times. Overall it will contribute as a second digit 120*3*10. As the 4th digit it will contribute 120*3*1000. Overall the digit 3 will contribute 120*3*(1+10+100+1000+10000+100000) = 120*3*111111. All that is left is to do the same for the other digits.

Comment: I still don't understand how 3 is going to be the second digit 120 times. I understand that we can have 120 numbers for each digit like 123456, 124356, etc.... 120 numbers where we have 1 in the first place and then 120 where we have 2 etc... but I don't understand the rest.

Answer (score 1):

For part b), there are $6^6$ possible numbers in total, as there are $6$ choices for the first digit, $6$ for the second and so on. Thus there are $\frac{6^6}{6}  = 6^5$ possible numbers with the first digit being $1$, and this is the same for $2,3$ and the other digits.

Apply the same logic to the second and other digits, except now the place value is $10^4$ instead of $10^5$. Doing this for the other digits gives:

$$6^5 \cdot (1 + 2 + 3 +4 +5+6) \cdot (10^5 + 10^4 + 10^3 + 10^2 + 10^1 + 10^0)$$

Answer (score 0):

For part b) again, the mean number is $\frac{111 \ 111+666 \ 666}{2}$. Since this is not an integer, and there are an even number of integers, the pairs of numbers will cancel out ($111\ 111$ and $666 \ 666$; $111\ 112$ and $666 \ 665$ etc.) and sum to twice the mean.

Therefore, the sum of all these numbers is $6^6 \cdot \frac{111 \ 111+666 \ 666}{2}$, which gives the same number as before.